# changing css based on linking data from response to html table

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

I have a html table created by a for loop like below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
var row = $('<tr>').appendTo("#zoning tbody");
for (var j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
    $(`<td class=${i * 10 + j}>${i * 10 + j}<\/td>`).appendTo(row);
```

how can I write a IF statement that says

if (the numbers in response match numbers in table run this code){
      do this
      } 
} else if (the numbers in the table are not present in response run this) {
    do this
    }

if a number that is present in the table isn't present in response do something else if the number is not present do some else.

e.g. I tried to write something along the lines of below but not sure what to put in the IF statement

```
function updateTable() {
    $('td.coloured').css({'background-color':'#8F8F8F','border-color':'black','border-width':'thin'}).toggleClass('coloured');
    $.get('php/test2.php', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
    $.each(response, function(index, item) {
console.log(item.beacon)
      $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'background-color':item.location,'border-color':'black','border-width':'thin'}).addClass('coloured');
      if (item.delivery_avg <= 4.00) {
        return $('td.coloured').css({'border-color': 'lime','border-width': 'thick'}).toggleClass('coloured');
      } else if (item.delivery_avg >= 4.01 && item.delivery_avg <= 7.00) {
        return $('td.coloured').css({'border-color': 'orange','border-width': 'thick'}).toggleClass('coloured');
      } else if (item.delivery_avg >= 7.01 && item.delivery_avg <= 10.00) {
        return $('td.coloured').css({'border-color': 'pink','border-width': 'thick'}).toggleClass('coloured');
      } else if (item.delivery_avg >= 10.01) {
        return $('td.coloured').css({'border-color': 'red','border-width': 'thick'}).toggleClass('coloured');
      } else {             
        return $('td.coloured').css({'background-color':'#8F8F8F','border-color':'black','border-width':'thin'}).removeClass('coloured');
      } else {
    console.log("key not found");
    $('td').css({'background-color':'#8F8F8F','border-color':'black','border-width':'thin'}).removeClass('coloured');
  }

});
}
 var updateTableInterval = setInterval(updateTable, 5000);
});
```

example

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 are present in response change cells 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 to yellow

1,2,4,5,6,7,9,10 are present in response change cells to yellow 3,8 are not present change cells to grey.

Comment: psst, when you have 1h free time, spend it on a vue.js tutorial and see what happens

Comment: thank you for the suggestion i shall have a look through that now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the IF at all, you can have your table with all the rows in grey by default and then change the cells to yellow from ALL the numbers in the response, so if 1,2,4,5,6,7,9,10 are present in the response, 3 and 8 will not change to yellow and will be grey

Also you should clear the table to gray every time you need to refresh the data.

Comment: I have updated my code the backgrounds and borders change fine based on the response data but when a number stop being seen in response the cells do not change to grey, if i remove the IF statements then it changes back to grey when the data has stopped coming in, have i written something incorrectly ?

Comment: Try not using `.toggleClass('coloured');`, for example, when you set all to gray use `removeClass('coloured')`, and `addClass('coloured')` when you colored.

Comment: Also move this line `$('td.coloured').css({'background-color':'#8F8F8F','border-color':'black','border-width':'thin'}).toggleClass('coloured');` inside the `$.get()` to reduce blinking

Comment: how would i put it as i just get unexpected token (